# How to override a parent class property attribute in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to override a parent class property decorated attribute like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Parent(BaseModel):
  name: str = 'foo bar'
  
  @property
  def name_new(self):
    return f"{'_'.join(self.name.split(' '))}"
  

class Child(Parent):
  name_new = 'foo_bar_foo'
```

but I always got this error:
`NameError: Field name "name_new" shadows a BaseModel attribute; use a different field name with "alias='name_new'".`

I tried this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Parent(BaseModel):
  name: str = 'foo bar'
  
  @property
  def name_new(self):
    return f"{'_'.join(self.name.split(' '))}"
  

class Child(Parent):
  name_new_new = Field('foo_bar_foo', alias='name_new')

c = Child()
```

However, `c.name_new` still has a value of `foo_bar` instead of `foo_bar_foo`. How can I override in the Child class so that the `name_new` attribute has a value of `foo_bar_foo`? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to include a setter in the parent class?  Or directly do ```name = 'foo bar'```?  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override property of pydantic BaseModel.

consider using init method.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Parent(BaseModel):
  name: str = 'foo bar'
  name_new: str = ''
  
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      if not self.name_new:
        self.name_new = f"{'_'.join(self.name.split(' '))}"

  

class Child(Parent):
  name_new: str = 'foo_bar_foo'

print(Parent().name_new)
# foo_bar
print(Child().name_new)
# foo_bar_foo
```